# Calcular horas trabalhadas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Tenho as horas padrão que o funcionário bate ponto. Ex:

`8:00 - 12:00 - 13:00 - 18:00`

E tenho as horas que ele bateu ponto naquele dia. Ex:

`8 - 12:06 - 12:59 - 17:0`

Preciso calcular quantas horas e minutos sobraram ou acrescentam naquele dia.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma função para fazer o *parsing* de cada uma das strings de horário, e em seguida calcular a quantidade de minutos entre eles:

```js
function parse(horario) {
    // divide a string em duas partes, separado por dois-pontos, e transforma em número
    let [hora, minuto] = horario.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));
    if (!minuto) { // para o caso de não ter os minutos
        minuto = 0;
    }
    return minuto + (hora * 60);
}

// calcula a duração total em minutos
function duracao(entrada1, saida1, entrada2, saida2) {
    return (parse(saida1) - parse(entrada1)) + (parse(saida2) - parse(entrada2));
}

// duração de uma jornada normal de trabalho (em minutos)
let jornadaNormal = duracao('8:00', '12:00', '13:00', '18:00');
// quantidade de minutos efetivamente trabalhados
let jornada = duracao('8', '12:06', '12:59', '17:00');
// diferença entre as jornadas
let diff = Math.abs(jornada - jornadaNormal);
if (diff != 0) {
    let horas = Math.floor(diff / 60);
    let minutos = diff - (horas * 60);
    console.log(`${horas} horas e ${minutos} minutos a ${jornada > jornadaNormal ? 'mais' : 'menos'}`);
}
```

Com isso, o código imprime a quantidade de horas e minutos trabalhadas, e mostra se é mais (ou menos) do que a jornada normal:

> 0 horas e 53 minutos a menos

---

### Moment.js

Uma outra alternativa é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), que possui suporte à durações, através de [`Durations`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).
A ideia é parecida:

```js
function duracaoTotal(entrada1, saida1, entrada2, saida2) {
    let formatos = ['HH:mm', 'HH']; // formato do horário pode ser com ou sem os minutos
    let inicio = moment(entrada1, formatos);
    let fim = moment(saida1, formatos);
    // diferença entre a hora inicial e final
    let diff = moment.duration(fim.diff(inicio));

    inicio = moment(entrada2, formatos);
    fim = moment(saida2, formatos);
    // obter diferença entre a nova hora inicial e final e somar ao valor anterior
    diff.add(moment.duration(fim.diff(inicio)));

    return diff;
}

// duração de uma jornada normal de trabalho
let jornadaNormal = duracaoTotal('8:00', '12:00', '13:00', '18:00');
// duração efetivamente trabalhada
let jornada = duracaoTotal('8', '12:06', '12:59', '17:00');

// diferença entre as jornadas
let diff = jornada.subtract(jornadaNormal);
if (diff.asMinutes() != 0) {
    // imprimir a quantidade de horas e minutos
    console.log(`${Math.abs(diff.hours())} horas e ${Math.abs(diff.minutes())} minutos a ${diff.asMinutes() > 0 ? 'mais' : 'menos'}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Lembrando que ambos os códigos acima assumem que todos os horários referem-se ao mesmo dia. Se tiver horários em dias diferentes, você deve colocar explicitamente as datas nas strings (similar ao que foi feito na [resposta do André](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/381146/112052)).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode calcular a diferença das datas assim que o resultado será em millisegundos

```
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

Após isso basta criar um objeto Date pra isso.

Por exemplo:

```
var diff = Math.abs(DataInicial - DataFinal);
```

Depois disso vc pode colocar no new Date que deve funcionar.

Comment: mas eu preciso da hora e nao da data

Answer (score 0):

Uma biblioteca muito boa para manipulação de datas é [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Por exemplo

```js
    const first = moment('03/05/2019 08:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS');
    const second = moment('03/05/2019 12:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS');

    second.diff(first, 'hour'); // 4
    second.diff(first, 'minute') // 240
```